# hclust analyse methods, R

Tags: r, clustering

I use currently the function hclust() for Dendogram in R. It looks like:

```
res.hc <- hclust(d, method = "ward.D2" )
```

My special interest is to understand, what the method I have to use for my data and where is a difference. 
I already took a look to the R Documentation `?hclust`

The documentation is very poor, I could find only this part:

> A number of different clustering methods are provided. Ward's minimum
>   variance method aims at finding compact, spherical clusters. The
>   complete linkage method finds similar clusters. The single linkage
>   method (which is closely related to the minimal spanning tree) adopts
>   a ‘friends of friends’ clustering strategy. The other methods can be
>   regarded as aiming for clusters with characteristics somewhere between
>   the single and complete link methods. Note however, that methods
>   "median" and "centroid" are not leading to a monotone distance
>   measure, or equivalently the resulting dendrograms can have so called
>   inversions or reversals which are hard to interpret, but note the
>   trichotomies in Legendre and Legendre (2012).
>
> Two different algorithms are found in the literature for Ward
>   clustering. The one used by option "ward.D" (equivalent to the only
>   Ward option "ward" in R versions <= 3.0.3) does not implement Ward's
>   (1963) clustering criterion, whereas option "ward.D2" implements that
>   criterion (Murtagh and Legendre 2014). With the latter, the
>   dissimilarities are squared before cluster updating. Note that
>   agnes(*, method="ward") corresponds to hclust(*, "ward.D2").

Can anybody provide me better introduction to this method and probably try to explain, how I can select the right method for my data (my data is very similar to ibis setosa dataset).

Comment: In addition to the documentation, read other sources. [This](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/217742/3277) answer here describes various linkage methods. Please look also behind the links in the answer. Ward1 and Ward2 implementations are equivalent in clustering results if used correctly. Their dendrogram looks may differ (that also depends on the software).

Comment: @ttnphns, thank you a lot, I think this is very helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

Partially answered in comments:

In addition to the documentation, read other sources. [This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/195446/choosing-the-right-linkage-method-for-hierarchical-clustering/217742#217742) answer here describes various linkage methods. Please look also behind the links in the answer. Ward1 and Ward2 implementations are equivalent in clustering results if used correctly. Their dendrogram looks may differ (that also depends on the software). – ttnphns