# Do heights between branches in R's heatmap dendrogram reflect true distances?

Tags: r, clustering, dendrogram, heatmap

We are trying to interpret a heatmap that looks like this:

[image]

... and plotted with this plotting code:

```
heatmap(ourdata,
    col=cluster_colors,
    distfun = function(x) dist(x, method="euclidean"),
    hclustfun = function(x) hclust(x, method="complete"),
    margins=c(8,18),
);
```

Visually, it seems quite clear that there are different "heights" between the branches in the dendrogram, which we assume would correspond to relative distances between the columns and/or clusters.

**Question 1:** Is this correct: do the heights correspond to clustering distances?

**Question 2:** Where can we find evidence of this? We haven't been able to find the answer from `help(heatmap)` nor `help(hclust)` (nor `help(dist)`, although that is not expected either).

Comment: `do the heights correspond to clustering distances?` They should. They should correspond normally to the colligation coefficient computed as the linkage with that linkage method (in your example - complete method). Read [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/217742/3277), especially "Dendrogram" paragraph. However, what is plotted by your specific function should be known from its documentation, _always_ read documentation attentively.

Comment: `We haven't been able to find the answer from...` If documentation is scarce try to do the same hierarchical clustering by another, better documented function/package, and compare the looks of the dendrogram; the looks (relative branch levels) is expected to be the same (left-right sequence of objects, however, might vary a bit).

Answer (score 1):

With `complete` linkage, it is supposedly the *maximum* of the pairwise distances from one cluster to the other.

With `single` it would be the minimum between the two clusters.