# Applying Ward's method for calculating linkage

Tags: hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram, ward

For an assignment, I have used iPython to create the dendrogram below, using Ward's method and Euclidean distance, from the following data:
$$a=(0,0)$$
$$b=(1,2)$$
$$c=(3,4)$$
$$d=(4,1)$$
$$e=(2,2)$$
[image]
where dist({a},{b,e}) = 2.88, and dist({a,b,e},{c,d})=4.27.

How are these values derived? I've tried using the recursive method given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ward's_method), but am not getting the same results.

Any help muchos appreciated.

I know that dist(a,b)=$\sqrt{5}$, dist(a,e)=$\sqrt{8}$, so using the formula on the wikipedia page, I have dist({a},{b,e})=$\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{5} + \frac{2}{3}\sqrt{8} - \frac{1}{3} = 3.04$.
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: done - btw this isn't a homework question, it's a question I've put together myself for a quiz

Comment: The Talk page at the wikipedia article discusses all the necessary details. Please see also in http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/217742/3277. And remember Ward's method operates on _squared_ distances.

Answer (score 3):

Having banged my head on the wall for the last 2 hours on this, I feel your pain.

The result is the square root of the increase in within-cluster sum of squares (vs. cluster means), multiplied by $\sqrt{2}$ for some reason.

$$
\sqrt{
2
\left(
\sum_{i \in (C_1 \cup C_2)} \lVert \vec x_i - \bar x_{C_1 \cup C_2} \rVert^2
-
\sum_{i \in (C_1)} \lVert \vec x_i - \bar x_{C_1} \rVert^2
-
\sum_{i \in (C_2)} \lVert \vec x_i - \bar x_{C_2} \rVert^2
\right)
}
$$

For $C_1 = \{ a, b, e \}, C_2 = \{ c,d \}$ the result is $4.27$ as you require.

As for how exactly they are derived, depends on the specifics of the algorithm in use.

Comment: Michael, the Talk page of Wikipedia's Ward method article explains that sqrt(2)

Answer (score 0):

The right is:
$$dist(\{a\},\{b,e\})=\left(\frac23\right)\cdot 5+\left(\frac23\right)\cdot 8–\frac13\cdot 1=\frac{25}3$$
Then
$$dist(\{a\},\{b,e\})=\sqrt{\frac{25}3}=2.88$$