# A valid distance metric for high dimensional data

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, similarities, metric

I asked a question about forming a valid distance metric yesterday ([Link1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/126453/how-to-get-a-valid-distance-metric)) and got some very good answer; however, I have got some more questions about forming a proper distance metric for high dimensional data.

1. Why is triangle inequality so important to make a valid distance metric? Maybe it is too broad to ask this, but I haven't got a simple example in my mind. Not sure if you people can think a simple scenario to explain this with some context?
2. As mentioned in my previous post ([Link1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/126453/how-to-get-a-valid-distance-metric)), I think Cosine similarity is the same thing as dot product. Am I right? If so, dot product is not a valid distance metric because it does not have the triangle inequality property and etc. If we transform the similarity measured by dot product into Angular similarity, will it be a proper distance metric?
3. Regarding to the Euclidean distance, there is another post ([Link2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/99171/why-is-euclidean-distance-not-a-good-metric-in-high-dimensions?rq=1)) saying that it is not a good metric in high dimensions. As my data vectors are in high dimensional space, I am wondering if some distance metric suffer from the curse of dimensionality?
4. Regarding to the point C above, considering the dimensionality, will a fractional distance metric be a better distance metric? ([Link3](http://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-44503-X_27.pdf))

Thanks very much! A

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For high-dimensional data, **shared-nearest-neighbor distances** have been reported to work in

> Houle et al., **Can Shared-Neighbor Distances Defeat the Curse of Dimensionality?** Scientific and Statistical Database Management. Lecture Notes in Computer Science 6187. p. 482. doi:10.1007/978-3-642-13818-8_34

Fractional distances are known to be not metric. $L_p$ is only a metric for $p\geq 1$, you'll find this restriction in every proof of the metric properties of Minkowski norms.