# Why is it bad to use Pearson distance in K-means clustering?

Tags: correlation, clustering, k-means, distance

I have implemented this algorithm in MATLAB and when I produce plots I notice that using Euclidean distance, I usually get presented with a clear pattern (sum of squares decreases with the number of iterations). However, when I run the algorithm using the modified Pearson correlation distance (1 - r, where r is the Pearson correlation coefficient), sometimes I would see no trend at all. In fact, on some occasions the sum of squares seems to increase with the number of iterations.

Is there a reason for this? Also I know that Euclidean distance is the preferred metric for this algorithm, but does it have any drawbacks?

Comment: Euclidian distance doesn't account for the univariate variance of each variable. This could overestimate the distance between two clusters. You could use Mahalanobis distance (as an alternative)

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/81481/3277

Answer (score 7):

k-means minimizes least-squares. It does *not* minimize distances, although every other book reiterates this approximation. (Fact is, it optimizes least squares, which is *squared* Euclidean distance.)

As you may know, Lloyd k-means has two steps: 1. assign every point to the "nearest" cluster (precisely, the least-squares center) 2. update the centers with the arithmetic mean (the least-squares estimate).

### Replacing *only* the distance does not work

Because you change the objective only in 1., but not in step 2. To converge, both need to optimize the same objective!

Counterexample for Pearson:

Assume that the two objects (0,1,2,3,4) and (4,3,2,1,0) are assigned to the same cluster. The arithmetic mean is (2,2,2,2,2) Pearson distance to this center is no longer defined.

### Don't forget the "mean" in k-means!