# Is there a situation when one would use L1 norm over L2 norm in k-means algorithm?

Tags: clustering, k-means

Is there a situation when one would use L1 norm over L2 norm in k-means algorithm?

In most of the articles online, k-means all deal with l2-norm. L1 norm does not seem to be useful because it is not differentiable. However, when looking at only places where the norm is differentiable, is there a case for one to use l1 norm in k-means algorithm?

Comment: "Mean" is about L2 and euclidean distances and squared deviations. http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/81481/3277

Answer (score 4):

I cannot think of a general case where this would consistently prove to be better/worse. Data-specific cases may arise, but the only thing required to make the k-means algorithm work is any kind of metric.

In general, for $L_p$ being the norm of choice, the higher you choose $p$, the more important the largest single feature/variable distance becomes. Taking this to the extreme, for $p \rightarrow \infty$ and observations $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$, $distance(L_p, x_1, x_2) = max_i\{x_{1,i} - x_{2,i}\}$. (Here, we assume we have $x_{1} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $1 \leq i \leq n$, so $i$ indexes the features).

Building on this, you could say that the larger you choose $p$, the more weight your metric will put on  the largest distance between two observations when clustering. The opposite counter-extreme is $p=1$, where all distances receive the same weight and the combination of the absolute valued differences is linear.

I hope this helps you - let me know if I have not been clear enough.

Comment: **No**. It is not sufficient to provide "any kind of metric". Because of the *mean* in k-means. You can find some **counterexamples** here on Stackoverflow e.g. for Pearson Correlation. Only for Bregman divergences, k-means is proven to converge.

Comment: Dang! Thanks for pointing this out - learnt something today! :)

Answer (score 2):

If you use the L1 norm, you *also* need to use the **median** instead of the mean. Because the median is the L1 estimator of location, whereas the mean is the L2 estimator.

That is known as the [k-medians algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-medians_clustering).

> P. S. Bradley, O. L. Mangasarian, and W. N. Street, "**Clustering via Concave Minimization**," in Advances in Neural Information Processing Systems, vol. 9, M. C. Mozer, M. I. Jordan, and T. Petsche, Eds. Cambridge, MA: MIT Press, 1997, pp. 368–374.

Answer (score 0):

I think one reason is that, the "mean" procedure minimizes sum of L2 norms but not L1 norms.

Comment: But given that the standard algorithm is just heuristic search, couldn't it easily be modified to minimize the sum of L1 norms as well? I think a bigger concern is what would happen to the properties of the solution under L1 minimization

Comment: maybe... I do not know how most packages implement kmeans. I thought they just use "means". But at least, L2 norm is related to variances but L1 norm does not.

Comment: The standard algorithm is not just "heuristic search". It's a L2 optimizarion.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse ok, but all the same couldn't you swap out WSS with an L1 equivalent? Or does Lloyd use math specific to thr L2 norm?

Comment: Yes: the *mean* is specific to minimizing L2. It does not minimize other distances. See my answer, and the linked duplicate questions answers for more details.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse, oh, I was assuming we'd be using medians as well. My mistake