# Why is it wrong to apply k-means to a distance matrix?

Tags: clustering, k-means, distance

There are several threads discussing clustering analysis of a distance matrix and they dismiss use of the k-means algorithm. Here are two examples:

- [Perform K-means (or its close kin) clustering with only a distance matrix, not points-by-features data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32925/perform-k-means-or-its-close-kin-clustering-with-only-a-distance-matrix-not-p)
- [What does it mean to apply k-means algorithm on transformed distance matrix?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/376609/what-does-it-mean-to-apply-k-means-algorithm-on-transformed-distance-matrix)

However, it is hard to come by an intuitive (and ideally visual) explanation why it is wrong to apply k-means to a distance matrix. It will be really helpful is someone can explain this.

Comment: Your first link makes the basic point that you cannot calculate a *mean* without values to average.  So it suggested $k$-*mediods* instead

Comment: My answer to the question in the first link says that it is possible (and how) to apply k-means to a distance matrix and that it is implied that the distances are euclidean.