# K-medoids: Is there any constraint about the choice of the distance?

Tags: clustering, k-medoids

It is well known that the K-means algorithm is well designed for the [Euclidean distance](http://#https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81481/why-does-k-means-clustering-algorithm-use-only-euclidean-distance-metric) (or a minor variation such as the cosine distance). I have been reading the paper "[A simple and fast algorithm for K-medoids clustering](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S095741740800081X)" (that is cited in Sklearn - python) and It seems that any distance can be used. Am I missing something?

Comment: Beware that that paper has some errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you're not missing anything. Any distance can be used. The definition of k-medoids is for general dissimilarities, and nothing in it would make it necessary to rule anything out.

Note in particular that k-means is called k-means because the mean is the statistic that minimises the within-cluster sum of squares (squared Euclidean distances). That's the k-means objective function, and therefore k-means is specifically connected to the squared Euclidean distance (personally I find it deplorable and confusing that some people in the literature use the term for something more general that doesn't necessarily lead to k *means*).

In k-medoids, within a cluster you pick the observation that minimises the sum of dissimilarities/distances of the other objects in the same cluster to it, and this can be done whatever the dissimilarity is.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/264243)

Comment: Am I not literally answering the question? "Is there any constraint about the choice of the distance?" - "Am I missing something?" That's exactly what I tell them. If this is not an answer. what is?

Comment: Hi @Lewian, it was from the review, flagged because of its length etc.  So maybe you can explain in a few lines why any distance can be used? It has to do with the algorithm.

Comment: K-means minimizes the total squared error, hence euclidean or something similar while k-medoids minimizes the sum of dissimilarities between point, so you can use an arbitrary distance measure

Comment: If you look at the definition of k-medoids, nothing is ruled out, and there is no reason to rule anything out. How can I explain that? There would need to be an explanation why anything in particular should be ruled out, but there is none.

Comment: OK, I'll edit a bit.