# Criteria for a Distance Metric to be Compatible with K-means Clustering

Tags: clustering, k-means, distance, distance-functions

Referring to [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/81494/240967), it's mentioned that K-means clustering doesn't inherently rely on the pairwise distances between data points, and not every distance metric is suitable for k-means clustering.

Given this context, if we have a distance metric $d(v1,v2)$ for vectors, what criteria should this function meet to be compatible with k-means clustering?