# How to get coordinates when only pairwise distances are known?

Tags: python, data-visualization, multidimensional-scaling

I have $n$ points with pairwise distances known, $d_{i,j}: 0<i,j<n$. Their coordinates, $\vec{x}_i \in \mathbb{R}^k: 0 <i<n$, are unknown. I can set up $n^2 - n$ equations to solve for coordinates:

$$
(\vec{x}_i - \vec{x}_j) \cdot (\vec{x}_i - \vec{x}_j)^T=d_{i,j}^2, i \neq j
$$

Assuming coordinates are $k$-dimensional, this system of equations will have a single solution if $(n^2-n)/2 \geq k \cdot n$ i.e. enough equations to cover the number of variables ($n$ points times $k$ dimensions). Otherwise there will be infinitely many solutions.

In either case, are their algorithms for getting coordinates (or one possible solution) only from pairwise distances? I want to apply this in a python codebase - do existing libraries implement this?

Comment: This topic is [tag:multidimensional-scaling].

Comment: See even more answers here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/32925/3277