# Can I use k-means with a distance matrix composed of percentages?

Tags: clustering, k-means, distance-functions, hierarchical-clustering

I have objects o1, o2,...,on and for each pair I calculate a value that measures the pair's difference. This is a percentage, so for example o1o2 differ by 56%. Now I want to cluster this data. I can see how a hierarchical clustering analysis would fit e.g. o5o6 are the closest pair, now which of the rest are closest to either o5 or o6, and so on.

My question is: can I apply a k-means analysis as well? It seems to me k-means requires (x,y) type data but I may be wrong. Perhaps k-means requires data with levels of measurement: (ratio, ratio) and hierarchical requires (nominal, nominal, ratio)? Or maybe there is a better technique?

Comment: possible duplicate of [k-means implementation with custom distance matrix in input](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12495/k-means-implementation-with-custom-distance-matrix-in-input) [Is it possible to specify your own distance function using scikit-learn K-Means Clustering?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529625/is-it-possible-to-specify-your-own-distance-function-using-scikit-learn-k-means)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

k-means is called k-means because it needs to **compute means**.

So yes, **k-means requires coordinate data**. Usually, the data should also be *continuous* and *linear scaled* for the mean to make sense. Technically you can run k-means on binary data, but the result will not be binary anymore, and may not make much sense.

(And the means *must* minimize your objective, otherwise it may fail to converge - so your distance function should be sum-of-squared-errors, because that is what the mean minimizes)

Furthermore, **a distance matrix is useless for k-means**. Because k-means only computes squared Euclidean distances point-to-*mean*, and *not point-to-point*.