# DTW time warping with time series: statistical soundness

Tags: data-mining, hierarchical-clustering, dynamic-time-warping

taking off from this topic here ([Hierarchical clustering, linkage methods and dynamic time warping](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/137291/hierarchical-clustering-linkage-methods-and-dynamic-time-warping)) and from this ([Dynamic Time Warping Clustering](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/131281/dynamic-time-warping-clustering)) I was wondering if anyone could tell me what could make realiable the results of running a dtw / hierarchical clustering with time series (or a sound procedure in this case). I have read that its statistical soundness might be in jeopardy so, before I stress my CPU to death for no reason, I was wondering if anyone could shed any light on the matter.

Comment: What did you hear was wrong with its statistical soundness?

Comment: unless I got the methods mixed up (with k-means method) - which is entirely possible -, the method could have problems when series are very similar but shifted